# Different dataTables output (json and xml) with same approach in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json, datatable

I'm kinda new in JQuery so there may be something I'm missing out in this specific case.
I wrote two functions,one getting data from server as XML and other in JSON. In both cases data is presented into HTML table and now I want to format that HTML table with dataTables library(http://datatables.net/usage/) .
 I used pretty much the same approach in both cases as you can see in code below but in XML table **there is no search bar and pagination at the footer and header of the table as there is in case with JSON.** Datatables are properly configured and loaded in both cases because tables have that default DataTable formatting but there is someting with XML that is not allowing to put pagination and searchbar to the table.What could be the problem here. Please help !

```
/*Generating HTML table from XML*/
$('#generiraj_xml').click(function (event) {
    var url = 'http://arka.foi.hr/WebDiP/2013/materijali/dz3_dio2/korisnici.xml';

    $('#content').empty();

    var tablica = $('<table id="table_generated_xml" border="1px">');
    tablica.append(
        '<caption><b>Tablica generirana iz XML-a</b></caption>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<thead>' +
            '<th>korisnik</th>' +
            '<th>status</th>' +
            '<th>tip</th>' +
            '<th>korisnicko ime</th>' +
            '<th>ime</th>' +
            '<th>prezime</th>' +
            '<th>email</th>' +
            '<th>slika</th>' +
            '<th>kod</th>' +
            '<th>prijave</th>' +
            '<th>blokada</th>' +
            '<th>lozinka</th>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</thead>'
    );

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function (data) {
            var tbody = $("<tbody>");
            $(data).find('korisnik').each(function () {
                var korisnik = $(this).attr('id_korisnik');
                var status = $(this).attr('id_status');
                var tip = $(this).attr('id_tip');
                var korime = $(this).attr('korisnicko_ime');
                var ime = $(this).attr('ime');
                var prezime = $(this).attr('prezime');
                var email = $(this).attr('email');
                var slika = $(this).attr('slika');
                var prijava = $(this).attr('neuspjesne_prijave');
                var kod = $(this).attr('aktivacijski_kod');
                var blokada = $(this).attr('blokiran_do');
                var lozinka = $(this).attr('lozinka');
                tbody.append(
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + korisnik + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + status + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + tip + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + korime + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + ime + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + prezime + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + email + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + slika + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + prijava + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + kod + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + blokada + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + lozinka + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>'
                );
            })
            tablica.append(tbody);
            tablica.append('</table>');
            $('#content').html(tablica);
            $('#table_generated_xml').dataTable({
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bServerSide": true
            });
        }
    })
```

outputs in something like this [image]

but it should look like this (search+number+...) [image]

code in for json you can find here : http://pastebin.com/MpCcRduA

what I'm I doing wrong?

XML result looks like this:[image]

And there JSON response looks like this. ( I noticed error, what could it be about ("tds undefined ???) ? )
[image]

Comment: hi can you post xml result and json result too ?

Comment: @viyancs hi, I added JSON and XML responses in post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. As usual It was trivial and stupid. I was not following simple LIFO procedure as you can see so **I closed /tr before /thead tag and dataTables couldn't recognize properly structure of the table and they could not perform search on datatable**.